# Sitecore User Manager extremely slow when using Active Directory Module

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

Does anyone else have performance issues when using Sitecore Active Directory module?
I configured it, we are using 26 different domains but that is not an issue, it just makes it even slower I guess, but when I open the user manager, it takes about 25 seconds to go to the next page in the usermanager.
I have about 8000 users in total.

On the other hand, when I go to the roles, I have about 12,000 roles coming from AD, and there is no performance issue whatsoever.
I tried disabling the profiles from AD, but that didn't make a noticeable difference. When I comment out 25 of the 26 domains in the config (leaving me with about 1000 AD users), there is a noticeable improvement in performance.

If I browse through the set, I can see that the cache created for the domain gets populated, but I don't see any performance improvement from that cache being filled. What is the cache used for? Just for batch updates? 
What is the difference between the members, memberOf and User caches created?

Thanks!
Erwin

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while, but going from memory this is what I recall:

The issue is that User Manager has to query AD for each page as you request it, whereas Role Manager gets all Roles and then pages through that cache. This is a limitation of the underlying .NET provider. The best advice I can give is to try to limit your query if possible.

Consider using the "CustomFilter" capabilities of the AD module as described in the Chapter 4.1 "Custom Filter" of the Active Directory module Administrator's Guide document on SDN: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/AD/Documentation.aspx